# Beaglebone Black GPIO pin behavior after program exit

Tags: python, debian, beagleboneblack

I'd like to be able to change the state of GPIO pins on a beaglebone black, using python, and have the changes persist the exit of the python program that called it. Also, I'd like to alter the state with subsequent program executions.

I'm running latest Debian image(as of November 15 2015) on Beaglebone Black Rev C, and want to use python 3.4 or 3.5.

The Adafruit BBIO library says you have to cleanup the pins when you are done, which makes it seem that "fire-and-forget" gpio pin state changing program executions would not be supported. I need to be able to do this because of the web interface we'll be launching this from, and  we can't always have a python script running to manage these pins.

This is the Adafruit example:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setup("P8_10", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_10", GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Hypothetically the solution would allow me to turn pin on at command line, wait arbitrary amount of time while I do other stuff, and then change the state at command line again:

```
$python3 turn_on_gpio.py P8_10
$...
$...
$python3 turn_off_gpio.py P8_10
```

Comment: why not to write a single script for both operations ?
i mean if you turn on it'll wait for next command

Comment: because this is a multilingual project with multiple team members, and I am throwing this over the wall to someone who does not know python, but knows how to launch a python program. Conversely, he is writing in node.js and I do not know node.js. Basically he is writing an automated system that reacts to sensor inputs and turns on pumps, fans, etc. but he only knows software, and i only know python and electronics.

Comment: If that guy can write node beagle bone can work with BoneScript 
and also i think `python  script.py start ` isn't that difficult for anyone

Comment: the division of work on this project is such that gpio switching is up to me, and the rest of my code( sensor reading ) is in python, so I need a python solution. Yes, launching a python script from any language is easy, hence why I'm even trying to do this.

Comment: have you tried to just not use the `GPIO.cleanup()`?  If you are worried out that you can always just control the GPIO from the shell. http://tekuconcept.blogspot.com/2014/02/gpio-beaglebone-and-bash.html